# How can I get pandas Timestamp offset by certain amount of months?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, offset

Suppose I have a pandas Timestamp object t1.

```
import pandas a pd
t1=pd.Timestamp('2013-04-01 00:00:00')
```

How can I get another pandas timestamp, offset by k months from t1?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`relativedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html?highlight=dateoffset#dateoffset-objects):

```
In [135]:
k=2
t1 + pd.datetools.relativedelta(months=k)

Out[135]:
Timestamp('2013-06-01 00:00:00')
```

Or [`DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html?highlight=dateoffset#dateoffset-objects):

```
In [136]:
k=2
t1 + pd.DateOffset(months=k)

Out[136]:
Timestamp('2013-06-01 00:00:00')
```

Thanks to @AlexRiley for the suggested edit, `relativedelta` has been moved to

`pd.offsets.relativedelta` since `0.20.0`