# pandas time series offset in months using frequencies notation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

I'd like to offset a date in a DatetimeIndex by a certain number of months using a string but can only find reference to the MonthEnd version.

Here is my (incorrect) attempt

```
rng = pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-07-03')
rng[-1] - pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('2m')
```

This will return Timestamp('2020-05-31 00:00:00') when instead I'm looking for Timestamp('2020-05-03 00:00:00')

Is there an alternative to '2m' here which will give me that result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get pandas Timestamp offset by certain amount of months?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031138/how-can-i-get-pandas-timestamp-offset-by-certain-amount-of-months)

Comment: this does get it but I was hoping for a cleaner solution where I can just pass strings directly as this is embedded inside a custom function

Answer (score 1):

The [DateOffset method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) in pandas works well:

```
rng[-1] - pd.DateOffset(months=2)
```

Output:

```
Timestamp('2020-05-03 00:00:00')
```